# How to automatically load and unload .env file with variables

Tags: command-line, bash, environment

Is it possible to load an .env file when accessing the directory they are in and unload these variables when changing to another directory?

Comment: I suggest taking a look at [Direnv](https://direnv.net/) also on [Github](https://github.com/direnv/direnv).

Comment: This could use some more explanation for the actual solution.

Answer (score 3):

Yes with bash.. This will change directory to the specified directory as normal and if a .env file exists there it will source it.  If you add this snippet to your users .bashrc and source it.

```
function cd() {
    new_directory="$*";
    if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
        new_directory=${HOME};
    fi;
    builtin cd "${new_directory}"

    if [ -f .env ];
    then
        source .env
    fi
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want load `.env` while opening a new tab

```
function loadenv() {
    if [ -f .env ];
    then
        source .env
    fi  
}

loadenv

function cd() {
    builtin cd $@
    loadenv                                                                                                                                                            
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With **zsh**:

```
: ${ZSH_DOTENV_FILE:=".env"}

#
# Source local '.env' file (if any).
#
source_env_file() {
  if [[ -f "${ZSH_DOTENV_FILE}" ]]; then
    >&2 echo "Auto-sourcing ${ZSH_DOTENV_FILE} file"
    source "${ZSH_DOTENV_FILE}"
  fi
}

# Hook our function so that it gets automatically executed whenever we `cd`
# See special `chpwd` hook function: https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Functions.html
autoload -U add-zsh-hook
add-zsh-hook chpwd source_env_file
```

If you use the ohmyzsh framework, then you could also use this plugin: [dotenv](https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/tree/master/plugins/dotenv) (which essentially does the same).